# C++ Boost.Test - Where should class object be created to test it's method?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, boost.test

I am doing exercism.io C++ challenges which use Boost to test the code. I have 3 files, `bob.cpp`, `bob.h`, and `bob_test.cpp`(all below). Without classes, I can get the tests to run fine. But once I need to test a class method, like in `bob_test.cpp`, which attempts to test `bob::hey([arg])`, then I get the error:

```
error: cannot call member function ‘std::__cxx11::string bob::hey()’ without object
```

So I clearly need to instantiate `bob` somewhere(Ex: `bob bob;` ... I didn't choose the names) but I just can't figure out where to do it. The Boost test framework provides it's own `main` function(which means I don't provide one), so I can't do it there, and I kind of expected that Boost would instantiate the object itself, but it doesn't seem to. I have tried inserting `bob bob;` into `bob_test.cpp` and `bob.cpp` resulting in the same error. My question is, where should I then instantiate a `bob` object that can be used in `bob_test.cpp`? Being a C++ noob, my gut says it should be in `bob_test.cpp`, but I'm also pretty confident I'm not supposed to edit that file.

**bob.cpp**

```
#include "bob.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


string bob::hey() {
    return "Whatever.";
}
```

**bob.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// bob.h
class bob {

    public:

    std::string hey();

};
```

**bob_test.cpp**(just providing the first test(simplified) causing the error, the actual test is slightly different, I just want to get the setup working)

```
#include "bob.h"
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>


BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(stating_something)
{
    BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL("Whatever.", bob::hey());
}
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, but I have found a workaround where I am using namespace bob{} instead of class bob, in both the bob.h and bob.cpp files.

Comment: A still better workaround, though still not exactly an answer, is declaring the class method static. That way I don't need to create an object, and this has allowed me to proceed with the testing.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `boost::test fixture` to create an instance of class `bob` and then test `bob's` functions in separate test cases, see: [Fixture models](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/fixtures/models.html). E.g.:

```
#include "bob.h"
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

struct TestFixture
{
  bob bob_instance;

  TestFixture()
  : bob_instance()
  {}

  ~TestFixture() = default;
}

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_SUITE(TestBob, TestFixture)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(stating_something)
{
   BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL("Whatever.", bob_instance.hey());
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look at this. The thing is, I'm not writing the test cases, and they are not set up to use fixtures(plus I'm not supposed to edit them). I can only assume that there is some way for the test file to access a bob object from an instantiation by me, in one of the other files(bob.cpp or bob.h), or else that the whole thing has been set up incorrectly by exercism.io...

Answer (score 0):

`hey` is a non-static member function and you're trying to use it as a static.  You need to create an object.  This is C++ bitching at you, not Boost.

```
bob mybob;
mybob.hey();
```

You could also just do this: `bob().hey()`

Comment: I know an object is required, but my question is where an instance of bob should be instantiated. For example, I don't have a main function in which to do this. I know it 's C++ rather than Boost that has the problem, but it is because I am using Boost that I'm having the issue.

Comment: See test implementation of any Boost Library. These are a good source covering almost every case one can imagine. Libs directory under boost.